# Get status(like/dislike) or colour of node using accessibility service

Tags: java, kotlin, accessibility, nodes

Need to get the status (liked/Disliked) or colour of node component for like button using accessibility service, Node for like and dislike is same so cannot able to find whether the like button is liked or disliked

Node :

childnode:androidx.core.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat@a91f8; boundsInParent: Rect(0, 0 - 212, 72); boundsInScreen: Rect(25, 772 - 237, 844); packageName: com.google.android; className: android.widget.Button; text: null; contentDescription: like this video; viewId: null; checkable: false; checked: false; focusable: true; focused: false; selected: false; clickable: true; longClickable: false; enabled: true; password: false; scrollable: false; [ACTION_FOCUS, ACTION_SELECT, ACTION_CLEAR_SELECTION, ACTION_CLICK, ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUS, ACTION_NEXT_AT_MOVEMENT_GRANULARITY, ACTION_PREVIOUS_AT_MOVEMENT_GRANULARITY, ACTION_SET_SELECTION, ACTION_SHOW_ON_SCREEN]

Kindly give me a solution or any other way to achieve this?

Thanks in Advance !!!